# Very weird flash loading issue (Only happens in IE, Not FF)

Tags: windows, flash, internet-explorer, flashdevelop

I have produced a website for a design company 
http://www. paul bro okes des ign dot com

As you can see the first page has a flash image fader on it. This works totally in Firefox on all computers. But in IE on several computers, this fails to load... only getting to 25%, or 44%.

On my computer this loads 100% every time in IE and FF, but not on other computers.

The flash object loads images into it which sit on the same server in JPG format.

THANKYOU
I would be in your debt if you could offer your advice and experiences related to this issue.
Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I can't get to paulbrookesdesign.com to test it. The name doesn't resolve.

It's possible to have two versions of Flash on the same computer. I've had instances where my Flash plugin for Firefox was up to date, but the Flash ActiveX for IE was outdated. You update the latter by visiting the flash download page using IE, and it installs in the browser rather than having you download an exe. The .exe they give you when you visit the Flash download page with Firefox doesn't install the ActiveX as well for some odd reason.